# How to use mathutils.geometry.tessellate_polygon()?

Tags: python

I have troubles with this function:

> mathutils.geometry.tessellate_polygon(veclist_list)
>
> Takes a list of polylines (each point a vector) and returns the point indices for a polyline filled with triangles.

What is a polyline?

http://www.travellermap.com/tmp/delaunay.htm

I thought I can just throw a list of Vectors() at it like in this JavaScript example but apparently not.

Comment: Do you intend to tessellate / triangulate a mesh for export? In this case, `tessellate_polygon()` isn't the right thing. Use `Mesh.tessfaces` instead. See [API Docs](www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/info_gotcha.html#ngons-and-tessellation-faces)

Comment: No, it's not for export. I am experimenting with writing scripts for generating racing tracks for a racing game. terrain that automatically adapts to the curves of the tracks and such stuff.

Comment: It takes a list of polylines, not just vectors. Aka [[mathutils.Vector((..)),mathutils.Vector((..)),...],[..]]. A polyline is build from line segments between these vectors.

Comment: Ok, but do those polylines have to follow any special rules? Or can it be a point cloud like in the JavaScript example I posted?

Comment: A point cloud is not a polyline. Imagine the polyline as the outline of a polygon (note that it is contiguous!), every vertex is a mathutils.Vector coordinate. There is no need to repeat the first element as last.

Comment: Maybe this [addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?255237-Addon-Points-cloud-Delaunay-triangulation-amp-Voronoi-diagram) is of use for you .

Comment: Cool, I will look into it. What is this on the screenshots? :) It looks very similar to what i want to do with my track generator... Also thanks CoDEmanX for your answer below.

Comment: Looks like a wireframe of a terrain to me. Just tried it with 2.70a. Takes a point cloud (vertices) and converts it into a triangulated mesh in object mode. Can also build the voronoi diagram as mesh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tessellate_polygon()` function expects a list of lists (or tuples) for its only argument `veclist_list`. This allows for polygons with holes. You can commonly leave out additional sequences of Vectors, and just pass it one set of Vectors that form a polyine: `tessellate_polygon((points,))`.

Here's a script that takes the first polygon of the selected mesh object and uses its vertices as points for the tessellation function (actually, it's a triangulation function). A new mesh is created from the results, leading to a copy of the initial face at a first glance. But if you look closer, you will notice that it consists of multiple triangles (if the input was a quad or ngon), and they aren't connected. To show this better, I added an "explode" feature (move all verts of a triangle based on the distance between the triangle center and the center of the mesh):

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.geometry import tessellate_polygon

scene = bpy.context.scene
me = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

points = [v.co for v in bm.faces[0].verts]

tess = tessellate_polygon((points,))

bm_tess = bmesh.new()

faces = []
for tri in tess:
    verts = []
    for p in tri:
        verts.append(bm_tess.verts.new(points[p]))
    faces.append(bm_tess.faces.new(verts))

# Explode
for face in faces:
    center = face.calc_center_median()
    for vert in face.verts:
        vert.co += center

me_tess = bpy.data.meshes.new("Tris")
bm_tess.to_mesh(me_tess)

ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Tris", me_tess)
scene.objects.link(ob)
scene.update()
```

[image: Triangulated and exploded Ngon]